# How to find maximum value within multiple intervals?

Tags: matlab, max, octave

I have two arrays, `der_pos` and `der_neg`, which contain indices of an array `interpolated`. I want to get all the indices for the maximum values of `interpolated` in the intervals:

```
der_pos(1):der_neg(1)
der_pos(2):der_neg(2)
etc...
```

E.g.:

```
interpolated = [1,5,3,2,7,10,8,14,4]
der_pos = [1,6]
der_neg = [4,9]
```

So, I would like to obtain the indices:

```
[2,8]
```

Because:

- in the interval `der_pos(1):der_neg(1)` → `1:4` → `interpolated(1:4) = [1,5,3,2]` the max is `5` which is at index `2`.
- in the interval `der_pos(2):der_neg(2)` → `6:9` → `interpolated(6:9) = [10,8,14,4]` the max is `14` which is at index `8`.

I managed to do it using a `for` loop:

```
interpolated = [1,5,3,2,7,10,8,14,4];

der_pos = [1,6];
der_neg = [4,9];

indices = zeros(1,length(der_pos));
for i = [1:length(der_pos)]
    [peak, index] = max(interpolated(der_pos(i):der_neg(i)));
    indices(i) = index + der_pos(i) - 1;
endfor

indices % gives [2,8]
```

But is there a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: The second point under "Because" had `interpolated(6:9) = [,8,14,4]`, I changed `` to `` to make it in accordance with your `interpolated` matrix

Comment: what if the maximum is reached at two values in an interval?

Comment: @thewaywewalk I don't think it's duplicate with the marked question. This one asks about intervals of indices, not an interval of values.

Comment: @Adiel maybe I haven't read the question thoroughly enough, I reopend it.

Comment: though maybe not a duplicate question: the [`peaks` function explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262488/find-maximum-in-an-interval-of-a-vector/20263552#20263552) may be helpful anyway.

Comment: It may be helpful indeed. But for multiple segments you have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code. The function `findpeaks` returns all the peak. The loop then keeps indices of peaks that are in the wanted range.

I added a test to avoid errors in case of no found peak (index will be -1), and to keep the first peak if two peaks are found. You can use a `cell` if you want to keep all peaks in an interval.

```
interpolated = [1,5,3,2,7,10,8,14,4];
der_pos = [1 6 7 ];
der_neg = [4 9 8];

[~,i]=findpeaks(interpolated);
indices= -1+zeros(size(der_pos,2),1);
for loopi = 1:length(i)
    val = i(i>=der_pos(loopi)&i<=der_neg(loopi));
    if ~isempty(val)
        indices(loopi) = val(1);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
interpolated = [1,5,3,2,7,10,8,14,4]; % data
der_pos = [1,6]; % data
der_neg = [4,9]; % data
m = bsxfun(@ge, 1:numel(interpolated), der_pos(:)) .* ...
    bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(interpolated), der_neg(:)); % each row is a mask that contains
    % 1 for values in the interval and 0 for values outside the interval
m(~m) = NaN; % replace 0 by NaN
[val, result] = max(bsxfun(@times, m, interpolated(:).'), [], 2); % val is the maximum 
    % of each row, and result is its column index. The maximum is 1 for rows that
    % contain at least a 1, and NaN for rows that only contain NaN
result(isnan(val)) = 0; % If the maximum value was NaN the result is set to 0
    % (or maybe use NaN), to indicate that the interval was empty
```

This gives `0` for **empty intervals**. For example, `der_pos = [1,6,8]; der_neg = [4,9,6];` produce `result = [2;8;0]`.

The intervals **may overlap**. For example, `der_pos = [1,6,3]; der_neg = [4,9,7];` produce `result = [2;8;6]`.